# Whats the difference between Chi - Squared test vs Kolmogorov–Smirnov test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I have two histograms that I want to compare to see if they come from the same distribution. I use the the Chi - Squared test and KS test and compare the p-values for statistical significance. The two tests give me very different p-values and I was wondering which one to trust.

Here is a picture of the two histograms in question: [image]

With the Chi-squared `scipy.stats.chisquare` test I get a p-value = 7.50e-106

With the KS test `scipy.stats.ks_2samp` I get a p-value = 0.89

I mean just looking at the two histograms, I want to believe my KS test since the two histograms seem to be coming from the same distribution. But why are the p-values so different?

**EDIT:**
Thanks @whuber for the comment. I will provide some information about my data below:

The data is related to sports, the total number of wins in a single season by a team (these values can range from 0, 1, 2, 3, ... ,82). I sample an equivalent number of data points for each histogram (150 data points).

As for how I generated these histograms, I am using `seaborn.distplot` function as follows:

```py
sns.distplot([25,10,52,75,90,...]) # Array length of 150
sns.distplot([15,30,72,35,10,...]) # Array length of 150
```

Comment: This looks like an inappropriate setting for that chi-squared test. Please describe your data.

Comment: It's nearly impossible to determine anything by looking at these histograms because they do not reveal the sizes of the datasets, and that is *crucial* for interpreting either statistic.  Details of the chi-squared test also matter a lot, because the chi-squared p-value can be completely wrong if you're not careful about binning the data.  I'm sure that after you supply this missing information users will be able to give good answers to your question.

Comment: Thank you for a description of the data.  Could you now explain how you conducted the chi-squared test?

Comment: @whuber I'm unsure if I did it correctly, but I basically just used the scipy package. Calling the function as follows: **scipy.stats.chisquare(dataset1, dataset2)**

Comment: That's not how that function was intended to be used.  [The documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chisquare.html) states that the arguments are supposed to be "Observed frequencies in each category."  That explains why you got a ridiculously low p-value.  (Indeed, if the software were any good it would have issued a clear warning that something was wrong, because it's easy for it to check that the chi-squared p-value would be incorrect.)